# Masonry layout in Fluent UI?

Tags: fluentui-react

In Fluent UI's sample I see `<List>` supports dynamically rendering grid items.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/list

In our app we have grids in same width but different height and want them stack vertically in multiple columns, basically, masonry layout.

Exact the same layout in [CSS-only masonry layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout) but preferably using Fluent UI.

Does `<List>` (or other Fluent UI component) support masonry?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For build layout by standard Fluent UI equipment - use combination of Stack and StackItem components.

Comment: Leave out salutations and when stating 'has limitations' then its best you state examples.